# post a message to facebook wall from android studio project

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to post some predefined text to facebook wall using my android app. 
I read somewhere in facebook terms and conditions that fb does not allow external apps to post predefined text to fb wall.
Is there any way to add text to the fb post edit box?
If so pls tell how to do it.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> post some predefined text

That part is impossible and not allowed, because:

> Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message
>   parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the
>   person can edit or remove the content before sharing.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Obviously, you will never get the required permission (`publish_actions`) approved for posting predefined text.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation :)